# Selenium, how to take screenshot without opening the browser?

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to take a screenshot of a webpage using Selenium.
I have notice that the action to take the screenshot require to open the web browser itself.
tried to change `webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");` with `webDriver.Url = "http://www.google.com";` but no success, 
I even tried to leave it with no url and the browser opened with url of 'data', which now I understand that something else makes the browser to be open.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var capabilitiesInternet = new 
       OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DesiredCapabilities();
   capabilitiesInternet.
       SetCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true);
   IWebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
   webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");

   Screenshot screenshot = ((ITakesScreenshot)webDriver).GetScreenshot();
   screenshot.SaveAsFile("E:\\ScreenShot.png", 
       System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
   webDriver.Quit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No - you need to let the WebDriver request the page, otherwise how can it know what screenshot to produce?

If you're trying to avoid a real, 'slow' browser starting up and opening a window, you should either consider running that browser headlessly, as per:

[How do I run Selenium in Xvfb?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6183276/954442)

Or check out the headless WebKit browser [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) (or maybe [SlimerJS](https://slimerjs.org/)), and using almost exactly the same WebDriver API as you have now, ask it to produce your screenshots 'in-memory':

[Phantomjs - take screenshot of a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17189745/954442)

Just replace:

```
WebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
```

with:

```
WebDriver webDriver = new PhantomJSDriver();
```

(Obviously requires the application to be installed locally)

**Edit:** Just a note that the typical use-case for this is 'overnight' continuous-integration / continuous-testing when run from headless CI servers. However, it can be very easily added to other work-flows, e.g. for visual regression-testing, and simple one-off checks.

Comment: No, not an option, as your Firefox is a 'real' browser for users. But if you follow the first link it shows how to set up your graphics environment so that the rendering can happen 'in-memory' and so no user will see.

Comment: To be honest I recommend the PhantomJS approach - it's a very useful tool to add to your armoury - though bear in mind it won't necessarily render 100% the same as FF would.

Answer (score 0):

There's multiple ways to go about it:

- There is chrome flag `--no-startup-window` which should open chrome without window. I tried it, and it didn't work, however, you can give it a go.
- Use hacks - there is a way to start chrome without you ever seeing it, it works nicely. Just use `--window-position=-9999,0`, note that, TakeScreenShot() has some weird anomalies in my experience - it focuses the window, it runs out of memory randomly, etc. What I ended up doing is I wrote chrome extension which can take screenshots and return them back to selenium through JS.