# Phantomjs - take screenshot of a html page

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, phantomjs

I created a html page (stored locally) that uses Googlemaps API. My whole page is a basic google map with some customization. I want to take a screenshot every time I change some parameters in the customization so later I can easily compare.

**I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17197100/3901029) similar answer** and I got it to work on my machine. However, when I **change the url from an actual webpage into my own local html file**, Phantomjs only saves an entirely black image.

Here is my script.

```
var WebPage = require('webpage');
page = WebPage.create();
page.open('googlemaps_demo.html');
page.onLoadFinished = function() {
   page.render('myScreenShot' + '.png');
   phantom.exit();}
```

The file `googlemaps_demo.html` and this js script itself are in the same folder. Could someone explain to me why this code only works for an online url, but not a local html file? And how to fix it?

Comment: Could you test whether the html page loads?

Comment: @Douglas I just started learning js from last week. let me try...

Comment: @Douglas I can tell that this line: page.open('googlemaps_demo.html'); is executed. But it's probably not properly opened.

Comment: Edit: as oldbam suggests, the file can only be opened with full address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to specify file using a file:/// scheme and a full location of your file, e.g. file:///c:/local/page.htm

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I made it work by using only forward slashes in the entire address, like file:///c:/Users/me/......  Just curious why you switch two slashes?